# I am able to get Geo Points( Latitude and Longitude) but could't able to locate position on Map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

PLZ HELP!
THANK YOU in advance IF YOU Help.
I am using google map API in my android project where I need to locate device current position. I am successfully able to get current device Geo points (Longitude and Latitudes) but I could not able to show my current position in Map. Default map is showing and I am able to get geo points using Toasts.

Here is what I tried:  I am just copy and pasting all code. Please focus only on which is important. I was not sure so I pasted all.

For showing geo point into map I tried this 3 lines of code but not sure where to put this this code.

```
LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation).title("Marker in Current Location"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentLocation));
```

This is Maps_Activity.

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

private String lang,lat;
Double latitude;
Double longitude;
private Location mylocation;
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private final static int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS_GPS=0x1;
private final static int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS=0x2;
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    /*
    LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation).title("Marker in Current   Location"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentLocation));
    */
    mMap = googleMap;

  }
  @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    setUpGClient();
  }

 private synchronized void setUpGClient() {
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, 0, this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    googleApiClient.connect();
 }

 @Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mylocation = location;
    if (mylocation != null) {
        latitude=mylocation.getLatitude();
        longitude=mylocation.getLongitude();
        String _lang = longitude + "";
        String _lat = latitude + "";
        Toast.makeText(this, "Longitude: " + _lang + "\nLatitude: " + _lat,          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //Or Do whatever you want with your location
     }
 }

 @Override
 public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    checkPermissions();
 }

 @Override
 public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    //Do whatever you need
    //You can display a message here
 }

 @Override
 public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    //You can display a message here
 }

 private void getMyLocation(){
    if(googleApiClient!=null) {
        if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            int permissionLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            if (permissionLocation == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mylocation =                     LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
                LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
                locationRequest.setInterval(30*1000);
                locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
                locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                        .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
                builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                        .requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
                PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                        LocationServices.SettingsApi
                                .checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
                result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                        final Status status = result.getStatus();
                        switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                                // All location settings are satisfied.
                                // You can initialize location requests here.
                                int permissionLocation = ContextCompat
                                        .checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this,
                                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                                if (permissionLocation == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                    mylocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                                            .getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
                                  //  mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                                    //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15.5f));

                                }
                                break;
                            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                                // Location settings are not satisfied.
                                // But could be fixed by showing the user a dialog.
                                try {
                                    // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                                    // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                                    // Ask to turn on GPS automatically
                                    status.startResolutionForResult(MapsActivity.this,
                                            REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS_GPS);
                                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                    // Ignore the error.
                                }
                                break;
                            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                                // Location settings are not satisfied.
                                // However, we have no way
                                // to fix the
                                // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                                // finish();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
  }

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS_GPS:
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    getMyLocation();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    finish();
                    break;
            }
            break;
     }
 }

 private void checkPermissions(){
    int permissionLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    if (permissionLocation != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        }
     }else{
        getMyLocation();

     }

 }

 @Override
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    int permissionLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
      if (permissionLocation == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
         getMyLocation();
      }
   }


}
```

Comment: call `mMap.addMarker(...) `after assign google map `mMap = googleMap;`

Comment: just this line mMap.addMarker(...) what will be passed in argument?

Comment: I am still waiting please someone help

Comment: inside your onMapRead() ...
 `mMap = googleMap;`            
                                                       
  `LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation).title("Marker in Current   Location"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentLocation));
    `

Comment: i had tried it does nothing. no effect

Comment: its really hard here to get answer I thought I can get answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in `onLocationChanged()` Method:

```
if(REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS_GPS!=0) {
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mylocation.getLatitude(), mylocation.getLongitude());
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16.0f));
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(mylocation.getLatitude(), mylocation.getLongitude())).title("Current Location"));

        }
```

Here `mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16.0f));` you can pass any floating value which refers to zoom level you want . you can simply just try different values and see what is best for you.

Try this and let me know if it works.

Comment: in onLocationChanged method. I am also updating in answer so you might accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [My Location Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/location#the_my_location_layer) of Maps SDK for Android to directly get your device's current location as well as displaying it in your map. The full sample code can be found [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/java/app/src/gms/java/com/example/mapdemo/MyLocationDemoActivity.java).

Also if you already have your latlng coordinates and you just need to display your current location on a map using a marker, you can add the following codes inside your `onMapReady()` method:

```
LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
float zoom = 17.0f //Set a zoom level of your preference

mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLocation, zoom));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation).title("Current Location").snippet("My Current Location"));
```

***Note:*** Instead of using `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng()`, use `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom()`. THis works for me every time. Just provide a float value for your zoom level. Also, make sure that the value of `LatLng currentLocation` is not null.

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes . thanks . plz help me to stop continues location update. See this quetsion I have asked few days ago.. here is link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62267166/how-to-stop-location-updates-in-google-map-api]